# Comparing between an element in a list and a dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys

n=int(sys.stdin.readline())
dicti={}
for i in range(n):
    str1=sys.stdin.readline()
    key,value=str1.split(" ")
    dicti[key]=value
    string1=[]
while True:
   check=sys.stdin.readline()
   if check!="\n":
       string1.append(check)
   else:
       break
for i in string1:
    for key,value in dicti.items():
       if i==key: <-- comparison fails!!
          sys.stdout.write(i)
```

Basically, I read values(name and number on same line, separated by space)  into dictionary.
Then I read the queries into a list. Now I compare if the element in the list with the key in the dictionary and prints the element if present. 
I do not understand why the comparison fail,even when the value are same. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: "for i in string1" will give you each character , try "for i in string1.split(" ")

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Insights: 1 - Check the value of the key by printing. 2. Check the value of i in printing.. This must be enough insights for you to know what is going wrong.

Comment: @SarthakGupta No, string1 is a list. Anyway it will give below error.                   
 for i in string1.split(""):
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @YOLO my error is that the i==key comparison is not working for the same value.

Comment: @d-coder I tried the print statements to check manually what is the difference. Both are printing the same value. I must be missing something here.

Comment: You need to use ```if i.strip()==key:``` on second last line.

Comment: @PraveenMathew, check the length of both `i` and `key` just to be sure

Comment: Also you can just use `if i in dicti:` and dump the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

As per what i understood ,this will do what u want

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of key value pairs in dictionary."))
dicti = {}

for i in range(n):
    key, value = input("Enter the pair\t").split()
    dicti[key] = value

string1 = []

while True:
    check = input()
    if check != "":  # takes input till empty string
        string1.append(check)
    else:
        break

l = []
for i in string1:
    for key, value in dicti.items():
        if i == key:
            l.append(i)
print("For following values i equals key :", *l)
```

It gives the following output:

```
Enter the number of key value pairs in dictionary.3
Enter the pair  1 2
Enter the pair  2 3
Enter the pair  3 4
1
2

For following values i equals key : 1 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```